# how to reload the parent form

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 forms named frontend.php and backend.php. In front end form i have given the form action as '../backend.php' and input type is submit. I am uploading a file so that i included the action and type like above. when i submit the form it goes to backend file but its not reload to parent form ie. frontend.php. how can i reload to parent form(frontend.php).

```
<form action="../backend.php" method="post >
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
  <input type="submit" value="upload" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: you have to make a redirect from backend.php to frontend.php

Comment: i gave if($query){ header('Location:../frontend.php'); }. but not redirecting to parent form

Comment: try with full url. eg: header("Location: http://example.com/frontend.php");

Comment: this form is in htdocs->folder1->forms->frontend.php.

Comment: Then try with "header('Location:http://localhost/folder1/forms/frontend.php') "

Comment: i tried...sorry its going to next form( backend.php)

Comment: What `$query` reutrns? Is is success?

Comment: in $query i have written insert statement. $query = mysqli_query($dbconn,INSERT INTO.... ); if($query){ header('Location:localhost/folder1/forms/frontend.php');  }..i gave like this.